# Is there any library to determine whether a numerical value can be translated to a valid, printable, and meaningful character in a specific charset?

Tags: c++, unicode, cjk

I hope there is any library out there that provides such functionality so that I do not need to dig too much on charset specification.

C++, and hopefully Chinese, and hopefully Windows.

Comment: I don't think "whether a character is valid [...] in a specific charset" is a meaningful phrase: The character set *determines* the mapping of numerical values to characters. What exactly do you mean? Can you give a few desired usage examples?

Comment: @Kerrek SB I mean the numerical value can be translated into a character in a specific charset.

Comment: Well, that's tricky: Every numerical value in the range [32, 255] determines a printable character in hundreds of 8-bit charsets. For Unicode, there are code charts, and not all values between 32 and `2^21 - 1` are occupied yet, so that could indeed be looked up. Also, are you sure you already have raw values, or are you possibly dealing with a transformation encoding like UTF or SHIFT-JIS?

Comment: @Kerrek SB You can just suppose I am dealing with SHIFT-JIS (though it is for Japanese).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) is a mature library providing Unicode and Globalization support. Among other things it provides easy access to all of the many Unicode character properties, Unicode Normalization, Case Folding and other fundamental operations as specified by the Unicode Standard.

Comment: Thanks, and it looks very promising at first sight. However, can you point me that which function it provides can serve the purpose of the question so that I can save much time.

Comment: Looks like [u_isprint function](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#afa9b7fb8cced8d7bedbe2c9eae45f544) is one of what you need.

Comment: Seconded. The ICU lib is *the* library you want, if you need complete and commercially-quality support for Unicode. Its is huge, and confusing at the beginning, but it's worth to get to know it. It can do a lot.

Comment: @ks1322 @towi Sorry, but an additional question, what should I supply to `u_fopen` as `locale` and `codepage`?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to program with it it myself, but in the Unix world the Gnu Library [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/) is very widely used. It is also available for [Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm). It is probably a bit more slim then the ICU.